# Using CSVHelper to read a CSV file and need to extract columns to arrays

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I have this code here that works how I want, but I'm developing on .Net Standard and cannot use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` library. I would like to be able to do the same thing using `CsvHelper`

Is it possible with `CsvHelper` to, first get the header row as a string array. Second, get each row as a string array of items?

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser("FilePath"))
{
    csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
    csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
    csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;

    string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
    int arraySize = fields.Length;

    int index = Array.IndexOf(fields, columnExtracted);

    while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
    {
        fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
        string column = fields[index];
        Console.WriteLine(column);
    }
}
```

I tried the following code that reads the cells but breaks the line when faced with a delimiter because of the line `string Csv = string.Join("\n", result.ToArray());`
Is there a way to put all the info in an array? It's already stored in a string list but I cannot retrieve the data by an index.

```cs
List<string> result = new List<string>();
string value;
using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText("FilePath"))
{
    var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; csv.TryGetField<string>(i, out value); i++)
        {
            result.Add(value);
        }
        if (csv.Read() == false)
            break;
    }
}
string Csv = string.Join("\n", result.ToArray());
```

**EDIT**

This is my new code now after the feedback. But, it seems that it's leaving out the header row when iterating through the List that stores all the records.

```cs
 public List<string> HeaderColumnParser(string columnExtracted, string PathToFile)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            string value;
            using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(PathToFile))
            {
                var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();
                string[] header = csv.Context.HeaderRecord;
                int extractedIndex = Array.IndexOf(header, columnExtracted);

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    string[] row = csv.Context.Record;
                    string column = row[extractedIndex];
                    result.Add(column);
                }
            }
            return result;
```

Comment: Are you asking us to convert this code to use CSVHelper?

Comment: not necessary. I'm asking if it's possible to do using CSVHelper because it's lacking documentation

Comment: @GotBannedSoImadeAnotherAccount if you want the values as an array, why do you convert them back to a *string*? CsvHelper's documentation is adequate. It shows how to read strongly typed records, individual fields, anonymous objects, dynamic objects, and even how to load everything into a DataTable through CsvDataReader. It's quite likely that what you try to do isn't necessary. What this code does though is reproduce the original file line, changing `,` to `\n`

Comment: @GotBannedSoImadeAnotherAccount Ref your most recent EDIT, just add `result.Add(header[extractedIndex])` before `while (csv.Read())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if you want each row as a string array.

##### Updated for current version of `CsvHelper`

- `csv.Context.HeaderRecord` is now `csv.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord`
- `csv.Context.Record` is now `csv.Context.Parser.Record`

```cs
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Id,Name,Column3,Column4,Column5");
    writer.WriteLine("1,One,Item1,Item2,Item3");
    writer.WriteLine("2,Two,Item4,Item5,Item6");
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;

    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();

    string[] header = csv.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord;
    var columnExtracted = "Column3";

    int extractedIndex = Array.IndexOf(header, columnExtracted);

    while (csv.Read())
    {
        string[] row = csv.Context.Parser.Record;
        var column = row[extractedIndex];
        Console.WriteLine(column);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Before answering check for the validity of the question and if so, check for duplicate. Then if you have nothing, we are glad to see your answer :)

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer as to what was being asked.  It just needs to be peer reviewed.

Comment: @DavidSpecht I really appreciated the answer. It makes sense now. Just get the index of whatever column header I want to extract and pass into `csv.Context.Record`

Comment: @DavidSpecht just last question please. calling `csv.ReadHeader()` reads the header row and then goes to next line which means it won't be part of the array when returned or printed out. Is it possible to include it somehow or I'm missing something.

Comment: @GotBannedSoImadeAnotherAccount I'm not quite sure I understand your question.  `string[] header = csv.Context.HeaderRecord;` gets you that header row.  If you don't have a header row, you can just leave off the `csv.Read(); csv.ReadHeader();`

Comment: @GotBannedSoImadeAnotherAccount I think I might understand your confusion. `csv.Read()` does the reading of each line.  `csv.ReadHeader()` does not move to the next line, it just takes what was read and moves it into `csv.Context.HeaderRecord`.

Comment: @DavidSpecht Alright. I approved your edit. Also with OP's edit, the question is more focused. At least, enough as far as my opinion matter. I vote to reopen this question. Lets see :)

Comment: csv.Context.Record throws an error 'CsvContext' does not contain a definition for 'Record'

Comment: @LKC I updated the answer. Record moved to Context.Parser.Record and HeaderRecord moved to Context.Reader.HeaderRecord.